# vue show page after i18n translations loaded from backend

Tags: vue.js, fetch, vue-i18n

In my application translations can be edited by admin, so I need to preload them from my backend and initialize in the vue apps I have. So I found that vue i18n package has the ability to lazy load messages ([link](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/lazy-loading.html)) . But on their example, they already initialize vue with default (en) messages, but in my case, I do not have default messages preloaded. So I want to load messages from the backend at a moment of creating a new instance of the VueI18n.

Here is the `i18n.js` file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import {syncGetData} from "@/apiUtil";
import NProgress from 'nprogress'
import './sass/nprogress.scss'

Vue.use(VueI18n)


let loadedLanguages = []

export const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: navigator.language.split('-')[0] || process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE,
  fallbackLocale: navigator.language.split('-')[0] || process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE,
  messages: loadLanguage(navigator.language.split('-')[0] || process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE)
})

function setI18nLanguage (lang) {
  i18n.locale = lang
  document.querySelector('html').setAttribute('lang', lang)
  return lang
}

export function loadLanguage(lang) {
  // If the language was already loaded
  if (loadedLanguages.includes(lang)) {
    return Promise.resolve(setI18nLanguage(lang))
  }
  NProgress.start();
  return syncGetData('/api/translations/' + lang)
    .then(function(data) {
      setI18nLanguage(lang)
      loadedLanguages.push(lang)
      return  data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }).finally(function () {
      NProgress.done();
    });
}
```

also here is the `main.js` (simplified):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import {i18n} from './i18n'
new Vue({
  i18n,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

The loading of the translations working, but Vue render the template before they loaded, and instead of actual translations I see translation keys. I tried to use `v-cloak` but it did not help.

So what I want to achieve is, while translations loading users should see only the loading bar (I'm using `NProgress`, you can see the usage in the `i18n.js`) and render the app only after translations loaded (maybe not render but initialize). What I'm getting instead: both loading bar and rendered app without actual translations

Thanks in advance!

**Updates after Michal Levý asnwer**

Now, `i18n.js` looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import { syncGetData} from "@/apiUtil";
import NProgress from 'nprogress'
import './sass/nprogress.scss'

Vue.use(VueI18n)


let loadedLanguages = [];

export function initI18n() {
  const lang = navigator.language.split('-')[0] || process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE

  return syncGetData('/api/translations/' + lang)
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
      setI18nLanguage(lang)
      loadedLanguages.push(lang)
      return new VueI18n({
        locale: lang,
        fallbackLocale: lang,
        messages: data
      })
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error)
    });
}

function setI18nLanguage (lang) {
  document.querySelector('html').setAttribute('lang', lang)
  return lang
}

export function loadLanguage(lang) {
  // If the language was already loaded
  if (loadedLanguages.includes(lang)) {
    return Promise.resolve(setI18nLanguage(lang))
  }
  NProgress.start();
  return syncGetData('/api/translations/' + lang)
    .then(function(data) {
      setI18nLanguage(lang)
      loadedLanguages.push(lang)
      return  data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }).finally(function () {
      NProgress.done();
    });
}
```

and `main.js` is:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import {initI18n} from './i18n'
import NProgress from "nprogress";
import './sass/nprogress.scss'

NProgress.start();
initI18n().then(function(i18n) {
  new Vue({
    i18n,
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount('#app')
}).finally(function () {
  NProgress.done();
});
```

I can confirm that now messages are loaded before the Vue initalized, b-z in my `App.vue` I have a `console.log` in `mounted` method:

```
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$i18n.messages)
  }
```

and the output of console log is `Object { main_title: "Calculation", tab_you: "You", tab_friend: "Your Friend",...}` , before it was empty object.

But still `<h2 class="title-form">{{ $t('main_title') }}</h2>` renders `main_title` instead of `Calculation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `VueI18n` innitialization with something like this:

```js
export function initI18n() {
  const lang = navigator.language.split('-')[0] || process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE
  
  return loadLanguage(lang).then(function(data) {
    return new VueI18n({
      locale: lang,
      fallbackLocale: lang,
      messages: data
    })
  })
}
```

`main.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { initI18n } from './i18n'

initI18n().then(function(i18n) {
  new Vue({
    i18n,
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount('#app')
})
```

### Edit after Q update:

It seems the [format](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/messages.html#structure) of your localization is wrong. VueI18 is able to use multiple languages at once so all your translation keys should be contained in "language object"

Instead of:

```js
{ 
  main_title: "Calculation", 
  tab_you: "You", 
  tab_friend: "Your Friend",
  ...
}
```

your API should return

```js
{ 
  "en": {
    main_title: "Calculation", 
    tab_you: "You", 
    tab_friend: "Your Friend",
    ...
  }
}
```

...where "en" is language identifier

Check your Browser console, I believe VueI18n should warn about missing keys...

Comment: umm, looks like the way you mentioned should work, now it's loading translations before initializing Vue, but still, I see only translation keys, not sure why... I'm upvoting your answer and going to update the main question with new info/code

Comment: I believe it's a problem with format of your translations returned from backend. Updated my answer...

Comment: nope, I return object like this https://gyazo.com/883bc11d044454c4245046bd0104a23a now and still `{{$t('main_title')}}` not working, but I can get access like this `{{ $i18n.messages.en.main_title }}` which I can use  in case I'll not find any solution

Comment: btw asking question, get a solution and then change the question (add more questions into it) without giving appropriate credit is a way to go ...(sarcasm)

Comment: okay, you are right, picking up your answer :) Thanks!

Comment: btw, I did no change the question. The question was make the progress bar first, render the view after it WITH A TRANSLATIONS :) So technically your answer is only partially solved the issue, as it's still not render translations :)